# java file.renameTo() fails in unix

Tags: java, unix, java-6, file-rename

I have a java application that processes the  contents of a file, and then I need to move it to another location.

This is how I read the file:

```
    String filePath = new String("foo.bar");
    String fileContents = new String("");
    char[] myBuffer = new char[chunkSize];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    BufferedReader in;
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(filePath);
        in = new BufferedReader(fr);
        try {
            while ((bytesRead = in.read(myBuffer,0,chunkSize)) != -1)
            {
                //System.out.println("Read " + bytesRead + " bytes. They were: " + new String(myBuffer));
                fileContents+= new String(myBuffer).substring(0, bytesRead);
            }
            // close the stream as I don't need it anymore. (If I don't close it, then java would hold the file open thus preventing the subsequent move of the file)
            in.close();
            fr.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```

the file should be closed as I close both input stream and file reader.

Then after this I try to move the file to another directory using `File.renameTo(newFileName);` but this fails (under unix!, under windows it works fine)

Right after the move fails, I test whether I can create a file called `newFileName` and whether I can delete the original file. The new file gets to be created, while the original file fails to delete.
Interestingly enough I can delete the original file from command line while the application is running (right after the failure).

Any idea why is that or any alternative?

More details: I am working under unix and I'm bound to use java 1.6 for legacy reasons (thus I can not revert to Files.move() which is supported starting from java 1.7).

Comment: Are you moving it to a different filesystem/NFS?

Comment: Have you checked the attribute of files that has been created by your code may be JVM dont have permission to access the file or your application code is runs as alias which dont have read/write access?

Comment: @dogbane no I am actually moving it to a subfolder of the folder where the original file is created (the subfolder exists).

Comment: @VivekBajpai The java application does have the read/write rights (in fact it reads the original file - I can see the contents from some log files) and it can create files (I can create a blank file at the location I would want to move the original file to).

Comment: i know but why dont to check the file attribute with ls -l try it on both time when the file is created and when it fails to move

Comment: Two small comments: please close your readers in a `finally` block and make sure you do not swallow exceptions (`return null`) just to make sure `FileDescriptors` are correctly released. This being said we have had a lot os issues with `renameTo`, particularly on Windows shares and I would advise using the excellent [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what was the problem in my java application.

Basically I extract a list of files from a directory using a custom `FileFilter`. This gives me an array  `File[] foundFiles`.
What I do afterwards is reading each file in a while loop using the snippet of code in the question.
Right after the file is read for some reason I created a new `File` object using the i-th file from the array as parameter for the constructor

```
File file = new File(foundFiles[i].getName()); // File to be moved
```

and then I tried to rename this one.

Now for some reason this works under windows while it doesn't under unix (the file is somehow locked I think by the `foundFiles[i]` object).

In fact if I print the results of these lines

```
System.out.println("I can read foundFiles[i]: " +foundFiles[i].canRead());// DEBUG
System.out.println("I can write foundFiles[i]: " +foundFiles[i].canWrite());// DEBUG
System.out.println("I can read file : " +file.canRead());// DEBUG
System.out.println("I can write file : " +file.canWrite());// DEBUG
```

I get

```
I can read foundFiles[i]: True
I can write foundFiles[i]: True
I can read file: False
I can write file: False
```

It was simply enough to use `renameTo()` directly on the `foundFiles[i]` objects to make it work fine.

Hope this helps, but I don't know why the first version would work under windows and not under unix.

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyze the above observation...

```
I can read foundFiles[i]: True
I can write foundFiles[i]: True
I can read file: False
I can write file: False
```

The result is normal, because the ***file*** object has been produced via ***new File(foundFiles[i].getName())*** but the method ***getName*** provides only the name of the file, WITHOUT its filepath !

By creating the file via ***new File(foundFiles[i].getParent() + File.separator + foundFiles[i].getName())***, the results would then be :

```
I can read foundFiles[i]: True
I can write foundFiles[i]: True
I can read file: True
I can write file: True
```